# modify id of an element with the help of jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

i want to modify the element id with the help of jquery

```
<img src="images/AOL_button.png" id='http://openid.aol.com/***username***' class="indirect" />
<img src="images/google_button.png" id='https://www.***username***.google.com/accounts/o8/id' class="direct"/>
```

so using jquery i want to change the value of "username" to something else depending on condition

```
$(.direct).click(function(){
   var username=userA;
   // replace username from id here
})

$(.direct).click(function(){
   var username=userB;
   // replace username from id here
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('.direct').click(function(){
   var username=userA;
   //            ^--assuming userA is a var in scope 
   //            if it is a string, just use it below as "userA"(including the quotes)
   this.id = this.id.replace('***username***', username);
});
```

Comment: only problem is that i have opend an jquery dialog ui and taken user input and under the button section i cant use this.id. coz it will refer to input field inside the jquery dialog

Comment: @user1364146 Can you show us the relevant code? In your post it seemed like the click handler was for the image and you wanted to change the image tag src.

Comment: please answer this question i have posted the detailed code in here thanks for ur promp response\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437676/how-do-you-modify-the-id-attribute-of-current-selector-from-inside-of-a-jquery-d#comment13473366_10437676