# How do you modify the id attribute of current selector from inside of a jQuery dialog button section?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to replace username string in id of "indirect" class  with username specified by users in jquery dialog input field.Problem is i cant use this.id = this.id.replace('username', myvalue)  coz $this will refer to the input element inside of jquery dialog ui.... Please help me to sort this out by any other method

```
<img src="images/AOL_button.png" id='http://openid.aol.com/username' class="indirect" />
<img src="images/google_button.png" id='https://www.username.google.com/accounts/o8/id' class="direct"/>
```

================================================================================

```
$(.indirect).click(function(){
   $("#dialog").dialog({
     buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                if($('#username').val() == '') {
                    $('#username').focus();
                } else {
                    var myvalue= $("#username").val();
                    var provider_url_post= // replace "username" in google id with myvalue
                    alert(provider_url_post);
})
```

Comment: ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: `$(.indirect)` is not syntactically valid JS. @iambriansreed that's HTML4, not HTML5. The only limitations on IDs in HTML5 are: no whitespace, and at least one character.

Comment: @iambriansreed http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bunch of syntax errors in your JS, but assuming those don't exist in your actual code:

```
$('.indirect').click(function() {
    var self = this;

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                if (!$('#username').val()) { // just check the truthiness
                    $('#username').focus();
                } else {
                    var myvalue = $("#username").val();
                    self.id = self.id.replace('username', myvalue);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: this is not working it gives error as self is not defined.Thanks for the reply though is there any other way out?

Comment: Not sure I believe that. Is this code in a document ready handler? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: kk give me 5 min i'll add to jsfiddle

Comment: the code wont work perfectly in jsfiddle but i've just added it so that u can have a look at the full code

Comment: That's not the code in my answer. You wrote `self = self.id.replace...`

Comment: console in firebug (firefox) gives and error for ur code; i've tried exactly as u said

Comment: self.id is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

self.id = self.id.replace('username', myvalue);

Comment: The jsFiddle does not remotely work, nor does it produce that error.